# Bash: store redis-benchmark result to var generate strange string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I try to parse redis-benchmark result in shell script, I write the script but failed to execute.

Environment

```sh
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS \n \l
$ dpkg -l |grep redis
2:2.8.19-rwky1~precise
```

```sh
$ cat demo.sh
OUTPUT=`redis-benchmark -n 1000 -r 100000 -d 32 -c 30 -t GET -p 6379 -q |grep 'per second'`
R=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | cut -f 1 -d'.')
S=$(echo $R | awk '{print $2}')
echo $S
```

Shell debug show some confuse information.

```sh
$ bash -x demo.sh
++ redis-benchmark -n 1000 -r 100000 -d 32 -c 30 -t GET -p 6379 -q
++ grep 'per second'
GET: 166666.67 requests per second'
GET: 166666.67 requests per second'
++ cut -f 1 -d.
GET: 166666'an
++ echo GET: $'-nan\rGET:' 166666
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ S=$'-nan\rGET:'
+ echo $'-nan\rGET:'
GET:
```

Do I miss something?

## Comments

Looks due to redis-benchmark result is something strange, don't know why

```sh
$ redis-benchmark -n 1000 -r 100000 -d 32 -c 30 -t GET -p 6379 -q |grep per > todo
$ vim todo 
GET: -nan^MGET: 166666.67 requests per second
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will not be able to fix the *redis-benchmark* output, this will parse both the correct and strange formats:

```
redis-benchmark -n 1000 -r 100000 -d 32 -c 30 -t GET -p 6379 -q | grep 'per second' | sed 's/.*GET: \(.*\) requests .*/\1/'
```

But you should probably fix the input :D

Comment: Thanks, fix the input means what?